# Best practice - should Expenses be tracked in Opportunity Object?

Tags: custom-object, opportunity

should we use opportunity to track expense related to an account, or create a custom object for tracking expense. I want to know logically which is more appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll go out on a limb and say NO

SFDC has designed the Opportunity object to represent a sales process wherein there is an 'opportunity' to sell something(s) on a particular date (CloseDate) that can be placed into forecast buckets (Commit, Upside, Pipeline, etc.); that Opportunity goes through a lifecycle (StageName).

The 'somethings' that can be sold are represented by Opportunity Products which in turn are linked to entries in Pricebooks

You are swimming upstream by subverting the intent of the Opportunity to use for expense tracking.

Furthermore, if you decide at a later point to use Opportunity as intended, you will find that your logic will get tortured as you have two very different use cases inhabiting the same SObject

Comment: thanks for your good explanation. So, using a custom object will be the right choice.

Comment: Took the words right out my mouth. In general, "recycling" standard objects is a bad idea. Cases, opportunities, contracts, etc all have specific uses. If you ever have a doubt, it's probably time for custom objects. The only possible exception is if you need to use dated exchange rates with multicurrency.

Comment: @sfdcfox - excellent point re: `DatedExchangeRates` as they only operate (sadly) on a handful of out-of-box objects and not at all on custom objects